# Using rake with Teamcity gives a RegexError

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, rake

Every time that I try use team city to build a .NET solution using rake I receive the same

```
"Format_exception_msg : Invalid escape character syntax: /path to rakefile/ (RegexError)
```

My natural assumption would be that I have in fact a invalid escape character somewhere in my rake code, I admit that I've never used ruby or rake before, but the script itself executes without problems and behaves as it should when executed on the command line without the use of teamcity.

Furthermore, I went through my code slowly commenting out lines to try to narrow down where the invalid character could be and the team city process continuted to fail even with a completely commented out rake file.

Thanks for the help, let me know if more information is needed.